# Why does trying to remove a non-existing electron from a state give zero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, second-quantization, hilbert-space

**Setup**

Creating an electron that is already in a basis set is zero (Pauli's principle):

\begin{equation}
a_i^+ | \chi_i \cdots \chi_k \cdots \chi_l \rangle = | \chi_i \chi_i \cdots \chi_k \cdots \chi_l \rangle = 0
\end{equation}

**Question**

Why does removing a non-existing electron give zero?

\begin{equation}
a_i | \chi_k \cdots \chi_l \rangle  = 0
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}$Recall that the vacuum is annihilated by *all* annihilation operators:
$$ a_i\ket{\Omega} = 0$$
and that all the occupied states are created from the vacuum as
$$ \ket{\chi_i} = a^\dagger_i \ket{\Omega}$$
Now, if you apply an annihilation operator to a state which doesn't have the corresponding electron in it, the annihilation operator just anticommutes through all the creation operators (since $\{a_i,a^\dagger_j\}\propto \delta_{ij}$), hits the vacuum, and the whole expression gives zero.

Comment: Last question: What anticommutes means or refers to?

Comment: @beginner: $a_i a^\dagger_j = - a^\dagger_j a_i$.